# Vue multi-purpose components?

Tags: routes, vue.js

I have [a small app that lets you add, remove and edit recipes to a list of recipes](https://github.com/alanbuchanan/vue-recipes/tree/master/src).

Adding has the route `/add` and editing has the route `/edit`. I am using a component called `AddRecipe` for **both** routes.

The component simply behaves slightly differently if the route contains `'edit'` - i.e. the input fields are pre-populated with the values you are editing.

Here is `AddRecipeForm.vue`, the shared component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form class="form">
            <input v-model="recipe.name" placeholder="Recipe Name">
            <textarea v-model="recipe.description" placeholder="Recipe Description..." rows="10"></textarea>
            <button :disabled="nothingEntered()" @click.prevent="addRecipe">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'AddRecipeForm',
    data() {
        return {
            recipe: this.isEdit() 
            ? this.$store.state.recipes[this.$route.params.id]
            : {
                name: '',
                description: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        isEdit() {
            return this.$route.path.includes('edit')
        },
        addRecipe() {
            if (this.isEdit()) {
                this.$store.dispatch('addRecipe', this.recipe)
            } else {
                this.$store.dispatch('addRecipe', {
                    id: Date.now(), 
                    ...this.recipe
                })
            }
            this.$router.push('/')
        },
        nothingEntered() {
            return !this.recipe.name || !this.recipe.description
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I am thinking there are better solutions to this issue. For example what if there are more views that are required later in the project that also require the component? I can't keep checking the route in the component if I want a nice clean readable reusable component.

What is your preferred way of dealing with routes that require the same view?

Answer (score 1):

One common technique when getting too many `if`s is to use a *configuration map* (I made this phrase up), e.g.

```
data() {
    return {
        configMap: {
            add: {
                addRecipe: function () {},
                inputDisabled: false
            },
            edit: {
                addRecipe: function () {},
                inputDisabled: false
            },
            view: {
                addRecipe: function () {},
                inputDisabled: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here we map the condition, which is a segment of the route path, to options we can use directly in this component, so we can then write in template `:disabled=configMap[routeType].inputDisabled`.

And in vue, we can place `inputDisabled` in `computed`, `addRecipe` in `methods` to declare them more clearly, just like you did above.

And if the type of `add`, `edit` go beyond routes, we can define the type as a `prop` and pass it in (as a *config option*, just like we would any other *reusable* component)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it from [single responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html), which state if you have 2 reasons to change for a class(component in your case), you have to split the functionality in two classes. than it may seem like a overloaded component.

However, given current simpliciity of logic involved, It seems a nice solution till you can wrap the logic inside a function like `isEdit` but if there are more different type of checks coming into picture, you can create two or multiple separate components like `AddRecipeForm`/`EditRecipeForm` etc each doing single thing.